# Display text + checkbox button + jquery

Tags: jquery, html

this is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/u95y5k4x/3/)

What I have, so far, is a `checkbox button` that once clicked will display a text field. But at the minute this is just an `input` tag of type `text`, but this is editable. What I am looking for is just a plain text to be displayed. It does not need to be editable.

I also want to contol the text that is displayed with a variable. And I have this working in this example but again this is using a `input` tag.

**So to cut a long story short, what i want is text displayed that is not editable?? And using a tag that is better than a `input` tag**

Comment: POST your code here so your question is crystal clear before one heads out to JSFIDLE.

Comment: either you can readonly attribute to your input tag....that will make it non-editable....or you can use span and change the text inside it...$( "span" ).text("change the value");.....btw what do u mean by tag that is better than input tag??

Comment: That's `checkbox`, not `radio`!

Answer (score 1):

In your case, just add 'readonly' to the end!

```
<div class="well"><input type="text" value="click a button" readonly></div>
```